# Can someone tell me how to center a table like this in the middle of the page/div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created this table using an online tutorial and now I'd like to center it into the middle of the page, but unfortunately I have no clue how.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks. 
http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would achieve this with the following CSS.

```
table{
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/17)

Update 10/06/2014

This is only available for browsers that use the webkit engine (Safari, Chrome) but you could try the following:

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center
}
```

Use -mox prefer for Firefox.

Comment: it centers horizontally, but not vertically in middle, did misread the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `<div align="center"> Table Code </div>`

Your complete code is:

```
<div align="center">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Duración</th>
<th scope="col">Curso 20 horas+<br>alojamiento</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2 semanas</td>
<td>1.300 euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 semanas</td>
<td>1.300 euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 semanas</td>
<td>1.300 euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 semanas</td>
<td>1.300 euros</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 semanas</td>
<td>1.300 euros</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To middle center your table you can update CSS with :

```
html { 
  display:table;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
table {
  margin:auto;
}
```

demo : http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/14/edit

or :

```
html, body { 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  display:flex;
}
table {
  margin:auto;
}
```

demo : http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/15/edit

Answer (score 0):

Consider using lib: jquery.ui.position.js for centering things.

example use:

var sibling = "#" + this.previousElementSibling.id
$(this).position({my: "center", at: "center", of: sibling })

Answer (score -1):

```
<table align="center">....</table>
```

Comment: this is an obsolete attribute :(

Answer (score -1):

Set `table` `align` property to `center`

```
<table align="center">
```

http://jsbin.com/xiwayugu/12/

Comment: this is an obsolete attribute :(